Lattice width of $conv(0,ne_1,\cdots,n e_n)$
Given a subset $K \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ we define the lattice width of $K$ : $$\omega(K) = \min_{d\in \mathbb{Z}^n - \{0\}} \max_{x,y \in K} d^t(x-y)$$
With $K =  conv(0,ne_1,\cdots,n e_n)$ how to prove that $\omega(K) = n$? $e_i$ are the standard vectors of the canonical basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$
I was able to prove that $\omega(K) \leq n$, for instance taking a standard basis vector: $d = e_1$ but I'm not sure how to translate the conditions algebraically, since I don't see the lattice width geometrically.
Any help, reference and visualization would be appreciated.

Let us start with any $d \in \mathbb{Z}^n \setminus \{0\}$. This means that there exists $i \in \{1,\dots, n\}$ such that $d_i \neq 0$, i.e., the $i^{th}$ coordinate is non-zero. It is easy to show that for such a non-zero vector $d$, we have $\underset{x, y \in K}{\max} d^t (x - y) \geq n.$ $\ $This is by choosing $x = n e_i, y = 0$ (or $x = 0, y = ne_i$ if $d_i < 0$). In other words, we have established that for every $d \in \mathbb{Z}^n \setminus \{0\}$, $\underset{x, y \in K}{\max} d^t (x - y) \geq n.$
Since the $\min$ quantifier is over all $d \in \mathbb{Z}^n \setminus \{0\}$, we will show that there exists a non-zero $d$ that achieves the value $n$. By choosing $d = e_i$, we have $\underset{x, y \in K}{\max} d^t (x - y) = n.$ $\ $This is because for any $x, y$ that belongs to $K = conv(0, ne_1, \dots, ne_n)$, we know that $0 \leq x_i \leq n$ and $0 \leq y_i \leq n$. $\ $ This implies that $-n \leq (x-y)_i \leq n$. Therefore, $-n \leq e_i^t (x-y) \leq n$ and the maximum is achieved when $x = ne_i, y = 0$.

“It is easy to show that for this particular d, we have“ To me proof is already completed after the part where you show is at least $n$, but I don’t understand where it comes from

@jacopoburelli Are you asking for a geometric interpretation for $\omega(K) = n$? Or, how I came up with the proof?

Why it’s easy to show that for that d is greater or equal than n, which would concludes the proof.

@jacopoburelli I'm sorry if I confused you with my choice of words. I have updated my answer. It is easy because of the simple choice of $x,y$ I have mentioned in the answer. And the first part only show that it is greater than equal to $n$, whereas the second part shows that $n$ can be achieved for a particular choice of $d$.
